# Can I save the guards stuck in the walls?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

While in Hyrule Castle I noticed the guards were all trapped in the walls. I can't merge with walls here I don't think, so I feel like they might just be for visual aid so we know just how mean this lady is, but can I save them from their wall prisons?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to save the trapped soldiers, except by defeating Yuga at the end of the game. They are there purely for flavour reasons.